# Allow permit to cross-origin framing in PHP

Tags: php, html, iframe, x-frame-options

I have following view

[image: Page on honor.es showing the error]

Check out the [sample page](http://ab-flyers.honor.es/sample.html).

Once I click *Open Popup Editor* I'm not getting the the results, it's showing it's still loading but never finishes.

Then I checked this using Firebug and I saw the following error:

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.picozu.com/editor/?i=aHR0cDovL2FiLWZseWVycy5ob25vci5lcy9EZXNlcnQuanBn&key=A7lwl9MYGLNfVL7x&theme=galaxy&workspace=2 does not permit cross-origin framing.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: Cross-origin error shown in Firebug's console]

I tried to solve this by turning the HTML page into a PHP script and adding this code:

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
```

So this is the that PHP file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Brochure_Dashboard</title>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.classypicozu.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.classypicozu.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div> 
      <button class="picozu">Open Popup Editor</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">                                    
      $('.picozu').ClassyPicozu({
        key: 'A7lwl9MYGLNfVL7x',
        image: 'http://ab-flyers.honor.es/Desert.jpg',
        width: 900,
        height: 600,
        theme: 'galaxy',
        workspace: 2
      });
      </script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the error is still the same. You can [try it out yourself](http://ab-flyers.honor.es/test.php).

I just to want to know, is there any problem with my PHP file or how can I correct this error?

Comment: Since it's a header, it needs to go at the very top of the page, before anything, including whitespace, is output to browser. That is a general comment, I don't know if that will fix it...

Comment: @Rasclatt as you said I put that top of page which means like this but error is same `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>...` but error is same

Comment: Yeah, exactly. Like I say, I don't do cross-origin stuff, so I don't have experience in circumventing it, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I'm afraid you can't do anything because the X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN is set at the webserver of the iframe you include. It restrict any website to get it content cross-origin.

The same-origin policy is config at the core of the browser, only way to achieve it is modifying core functions of the browser.

Regards,

Comment: So your idea is I dont have option

Comment: Yes, If you dont have authority of the webserver of iframe you included then I think you should try something else

Comment: can you suggest an `advanced jquery image editor` that like `ClassyPicozu`

Comment: Did you register an api key at Picozu website? Check your api key with the key parameter in your `$('.picozu').ClassyPicozu()` function. I just read that if your register an api key at their website at `https://www.picozu.com/developers/embedding/` then you can embed their editor in your iframe. Regards,

Comment: yes I registered at Picozu website previously , my website is `http://ab-flyers.honor.es/` so I got an API key under this domain `www.ab-flyers.honor.es` , is this because of mismatch domain ? (beacuse I dont have `www.` part in my domain)

this is screenshot of my API key description http://s27.postimg.org/70e71n7ab/image.jpg

Comment: yes, `www` part is still count in same-origin policy. If you change domain you register at Picozu to match your domain then it should work. Regards,

Comment: Since this is a technical issue from Picozu side, could you please contact them for support? As the other side, I believe you have done every thing possible so just leave the rest for them to solve. Regards,

Comment: okay thanks lot, that what I thought , I dropped a mail I'll wait and see